# Unable to edit mp3 tags

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use jaudiotagger 2.0.1 library but when I try to set a meta tag I get this error:

```
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763): org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotWriteException: org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.UnableToCreateFileException: Cannot modify /storage/emulated/0/Music/01-Happy Christmas (War is Over) - John Lennon and Yoko Ono.mp3 because do not have permissions to modify file
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.commit(MP3File.java:722)
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at com.mypackage$1.onClick(Tag.java:142)
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-28 11:27:21.477: W/System.err(25763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763): Caused by: org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.UnableToCreateFileException: Cannot modify /storage/emulated/0/Music/01-Happy Christmas (War is Over) - John Lennon and Yoko Ono.mp3 because do not have permissions to modify file
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.AbstractID3v2Tag.writeBufferToFile(AbstractID3v2Tag.java:1165)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.tag.id3.ID3v23Tag.write(ID3v23Tag.java:741)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.save(MP3File.java:790)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.save(MP3File.java:706)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    at org.jaudiotagger.audio.mp3.MP3File.commit(MP3File.java:718)
08-28 11:27:21.485: W/System.err(25763):    ... 12 more
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
String mTitle = title.getText().toString();
                    String mAlbum = album.getText().toString();
                    String mArtist = artist.getText().toString();
                    String mGenre = genre.getText().toString();

                    if(tag != null) {
                        if(mTitle.length() > 0) {
                            tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, mTitle);           
                        }
                        if(mAlbum.length() > 0) {
                            tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, mAlbum);
                        }
                        if(mArtist.length() > 0) {
                            tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST, mArtist);
                        }
                        if(mGenre.length() > 0) {
                            tag.setField(FieldKey.GENRE, mGenre);                       
                        }

                    }
                    if(audioFile != null) {
                        audioFile.commit();                     
                    }
```

I don't understand why I can't edit the tag. Where is the error? How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the appropriate permissions to make changes to the file. Editing id3 tags involves reading, modifying and then writing the file to it's original location.

If you're running KitKat or greater, and the audio file is stored in the SD Card, Google have revoked developer's permission to modify the files.

Otherwise, it may just be that you haven't requested the write access permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```